# could not send the email using cron?

Tags: php, cron

Created the PHP Script to send the mail and set the cron job for to send for every 5 minutes.

But mails are not receiving.Please check the below script and help me to solve.

```
<?php
$to = "ravxxxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";
$message = "Error Message returned by"

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\b";
$headers .= 'From: anxxxxx@domain.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

cron tab: crontab -l

```
  5 * * * * /path/mail.php
```

Comment: So what do your log files say what is happening? We cannot look at your system, you have to tell us. Check your php error log file and your system log file.

Comment: check your php error log file.

Comment: I got the mails but there is 1 hour difference between the mails.But i set it to send for every 5 minutes.can anyone please suggest me why this is happening.

Comment: Don't check your PHP error log - check your error reporting, the cron output and your MTA log.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
*/5 * * * * /path/mail.php
```

What the above shows, per column:

1. Minute to run on, a value of 0-59: 5 means on the 5th minute of the hour
2. The Hour, a value of 0-23: * means every hour
3. Day of the Month, 1-31: * means every day of the month
4. The Month, 1-12: * means every month
5. Day of the Week, 0-7 (0 and 7 are both Sunday): * means every day
6. The Command: In this case, a command at  /path/mail.php

Comment: it is getting error :"/tmp/crontabx3aOob" unexpected  character found

Comment: I have updated my answer to describe the time values

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifying php path in the cron?

example (find path to your php binary, I am using an example one):

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/mail.php

Comment: yes i gave as */5 * * * * */usr/local/bin/php /path/mail.php

Comment: instead of */5 try 0,4,8,12,16,20